# How to send/receive extras to Fragments in SwipeView Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, arguments, extras

I am trying to use the Swipe View with Tabs in Android and i need to pass some variables to the fragments of the tabs to show a customized content, my problem is that I always have the bundle to 0 so I think I am doing something wrong with the sending of the extras from the fragment container page. this is the code of the fragment and of the main fragment page containing the tabs.

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).

        prof = getIntent().getIntExtra("prof", 0);
        id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
        bund = new Bundle();
        bund.putInt("prof", prof);
        bund.putInt("id", id);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // Text fragment activity
                FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
                fragment.setArguments(bund);
                return fragment;
            case 1:
                // Gallery fragment activity
                FragmentTwo fragment2 = new FragmentTwo();
                fragment2.setArguments(bund);
                return fragment2;
            case 2:
                 //Audio fragment
                FragmentThree fragment3 = new FragmentThree();
                fragment3.setArguments(bund);
                return fragment3;
            }

            return null;
    }
```

while the fragment code is placed in the onCreateView method

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle!=null){ 
    prof = bundle.getInt("prof");
     id = bundle.getInt("id");
    }
```

I can read the arguments coming into the fragment container but into the fragment I can't read them, what did I forget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `SharedPreference` instead of `Bundle` here :

Instantiate SharedPreference in your FragmentStatePagerAdapter :

```
SharedPreference mPref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myPreference",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Store `prof` and `id` to `mPref` :

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
    // below).

    prof = getIntent().getIntExtra("prof", 0);
    id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
    // store value in mPref
    mPref.putInt("prof", prof);
    mPref.putInt("id", id);

    // commit changes
    mPref.commit();

switch (position) {
    case 0:
        // Text fragment activity
        FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();

        return fragment;
    case 1:
        // Gallery fragment activity
        FragmentTwo fragment2 = new FragmentTwo();

        return fragment2;
    case 2:
         //Audio fragment
        FragmentThree fragment3 = new FragmentThree();

        return fragment3;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Retrive values inside `onCreateView()` of any Fragment :

```
SharedPreference mPrefFrag = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPreference",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    
int prof = mPrefFrag.getInt("prof",0);
int id = mPrefFrag.getInt("id",0);
```